# Why ToBindingList() method very slow?

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, datagridview

Hy,

I would like load full content of a database table to DataGridView with binding asynchronously.

I create two tests:

1. with DataSet and DataTables
2. with Entity Framework 6.4

Rows count of the table: 65.000

I attach my test code with EF. The data loading is much slower with EF (I insert the execution times inside the source code comments):

```
namespace AsyncGrid
{
    public partial class FormEF : Form
    {
        public FormEF()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new();

            sw.Start();

            MYHOMEEntities ent = await FillAsync();
            // Execution time: 1.8 sec, [with ADO.Net DataSet: 1.1 sec]
            MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());     
            
            sw.Restart();

            BindingList<SolarDataLog> table = ent?.SolarDataLog.Local.ToBindingList();
            // Execution time: 28 sec !!!, [with ADO.Net DataSet: 0 sec (not needed)]
            MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());     
            
            sw.Restart();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            // Execution time: 69 millisec, [with ADO.Net DataSet: 59 millisec]
            MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());     
        }

        public async Task<MYHOMEEntities> FillAsync()
        {
            MYHOMEEntities e = new();
            await e.SolarDataLog.LoadAsync(); // 65.000 rows
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

So the full process with EF is ~30 sec, with DataSet ~2 sec.
The ToBindingList() method is very slow (execution time: 28 sec)

How can I speed up (or switch) this method to load data faster?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your SolarDataLog entity contain any navigation properties to any other entities?

Comment: I dont understand why the time measurement wrong... I think that's good. 
@Steve Py: no, this is a single table without any relations.